# What chain is better about gas costs? Ethereum or Binance Smart Chain?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-limit, gas-price, binance

I am developing an smart contract and i want to know what chain is better about gas costs. Ethereum or Binance Smart Chain? Thank you

Comment: BSC is a copy of ethereum where the decentralization level is like the gas price lower than ethereum mainnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binance Smart Chain is cheaper and faster today, but I am not sure why because if you see the **gas averages charts** in the official scans sites you can see that the BSC costs are so much highers than Ethereum.

I think is because the BNB value is lower than ETH value.

Ethereum: https://etherscan.io/charts

BSC: https://bscscan.com/charts